# Computation difference between function and manual computation

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

I am facing a mystery right now. I get strange results in some program and I think it may be related to the computation since  I got different results with my functions compared to manual computation.

This is from my program, I am printing the values pre-computation :

```
print("\nPrecomputation:\nmatrix\n:", matrix)
tmp = likelihood_left * likelihood_right
print("\nconditional_dep:", tmp)
print("\nfinal result:", matrix @ tmp)
```

I got the following output:

```
Precomputation:
matrix: 
[array([0.08078721, 0.5802404 , 0.16957052, 0.09629893, 0.07310294])
 array([0.14633129, 0.45458744, 0.20096238, 0.02142105, 0.17669784])
 array([0.41198731, 0.06197812, 0.05934063, 0.23325626, 0.23343768])
 array([0.15686545, 0.29516415, 0.20095091, 0.14720275, 0.19981674])
 array([0.15965914, 0.18383683, 0.10606946, 0.14234812, 0.40808645])]

conditional_dep: [0.01391123 0.01388155 0.17221067 0.02675524 0.01033257]
final result: [0.07995043 0.03485223 0.02184015 0.04721548 0.05323298]
```

The thing is when I compute the following code:

```
matrix = [np.array([0.08078721, 0.5802404 , 0.16957052, 0.09629893, 0.07310294]),
          np.array([0.14633129, 0.45458744, 0.20096238, 0.02142105, 0.17669784]), 
          np.array([0.41198731, 0.06197812, 0.05934063, 0.23325626, 0.23343768]), 
          np.array([0.15686545, 0.29516415, 0.20095091, 0.14720275, 0.19981674]), 
          np.array([0.15965914, 0.18383683, 0.10606946, 0.14234812, 0.40808645])]

tmp = np.asarray([0.01391123, 0.01388155, 0.17221067, 0.02675524, 0.01033257])

matrix @ tmp
```

The values in use are exactly the same as they should be in the computation before but I get the following result:

```
array([0.04171218, 0.04535276, 0.02546353, 0.04688848, 0.03106443])
```

This result is then obviously different than the previous one and is the true one (I computed the dot product by hand).

I have been facing this problem the whole day and I did not find anything useful online. If any of you have any even tiny idea where it can come from I'd be really happy :D

Thank's in advance
Yann

PS: I can show more of the code if needed.
PS2: I don't know if it is relevant but this is used in a dynamic programming algorithm.

Comment: In the first case, is `matrix` a regular `list` of `np.ndarray`s? I'm asking because it prints without commas between its elements (as opposed to the way `list`s are printed).

Comment: What are the values of `likelihood_left` and `likelihood_right`?

Comment: Try it with the smallest amount of data that works, and gradually increase it.

Comment: @Seb yes it is a list of numpy arrays

Comment: @YannPOURCENOUX Then how come it was printed without commas? Did you edit the output?

Comment: @jirassimok one is array([0.090974  , 0.04598715, 0.34342194, 0.10491601, 0.03268547] and the other one array [0.15291436, 0.30185713, 0.50145506, 0.25501581, 0.31612119]. The element-wise multiplication gives the good result

Comment: @Seb Given that the first line break and colon are switched in the print call and the given output, at least a little reformatting was done.

Comment: @Seb nevermind it's a array of shape (5,) with object as dtype

Comment: @YannPOURCENOUX Please confirm if you accidentally switched the input data as jirassimok assumes.

Comment: @Seb in the second case it's a list of arrays because I typed it this way. I am going to take a look if it comes from that

Comment: @Geeocode In the second case i made a little formatting to make it more readable but i did not touch the output in the first case.

Comment: @YannPOURCENOUX It's mysterious that it would be 1D and have a `dtype` of `object`. NumPy should automatically treat that as a 2D (5, 5) `float` array, unless there's some other oddity going on. I think it would be good if you showed the code that creates the `matrix` object.

Comment: @Seb The thing is this matrix is one row of a bigger one. This big matrix is size (5,5) the thing is the rows don't have the same shape. Most are like matrix and one is just a (1, 5) array. This is why the teacher chose this format I guess so both those shapes could fit in one same big matrix of object as dtype. Anyway I think you pointed out the problem. I will reformat matrix as a (5,5) ndarray tomorrow. I will keep u updated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Seb I reshaped matrix as a (5,5) ndarray of float type and it is now working as expected. Thanks, I'll be more carefull with types next time :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap our discussion in the comments, in the first part ("pre-computation"), the following is true about the `matrix` object:

```py
>>> matrix.shape
(5,)
>>> matrix.dtype
dtype('O') # aka object
```

And as you say, this is due to `matrix` being a slice of a larger, non-uniform array. Let's recreate this situation:

```py
>>> matrix = np.array([[], np.array([0.08078721, 0.5802404 , 0.16957052, 0.09629893, 0.07310294]), np.array([0.14633129, 0.45458744, 0.20096238, 0.02142105, 0.17669784]), np.array([0.41198731, 0.06197812, 0.05934063, 0.23325626, 0.23343768]), np.array([0.15686545, 0.29516415, 0.20095091, 0.14720275, 0.19981674]), np.array([0.15965914, 0.18383683, 0.10606946, 0.14234812, 0.40808645])])[1:]
```

It is now not a matrix with scalars in rows and columns, but a *column vector of column vectors*. Technically, `matrix @ tmp` is an operation between two 1-D arrays and hence NumPy should, according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html), calculate the inner product of the two. This is true in this case, with the convention that the sum be over the first axis:

```py
>>> np.array([matrix[i] * tmp[i] for i in range(5)]).sum(axis=0)
array([0.07995043, 0.03485222, 0.02184015, 0.04721548, 0.05323298])
>>> matrix @ tmp
array([0.07995043, 0.03485222, 0.02184015, 0.04721548, 0.05323298])
```

This is essentially the same as taking the transpose of the proper 2-D matrix before the multiplication:

```py
>>> np.stack(matrix).T @ tmp
array([0.07995043, 0.03485222, 0.02184015, 0.04721548, 0.05323298])
```

Equivalently, as noted by @jirasssimok:

```py
>>> tmp @ np.stack(matrix)
array([0.07995043, 0.03485222, 0.02184015, 0.04721548, 0.05323298])
```

Hence the erroneous or unexpected result.

As you have already resolved to do in the comments, this can be avoided in the future by ensuring all matrices are proper 2-D arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you got the operands switched in one of your matrix multiplications.

Using the same values of `matrix` and `tmp` that you provided, `matrix @ tmp` and `tmp @ matrix` provide the two results you showed.<sup>1</sup>

```
matrix = [np.array([0.08078721, 0.5802404 , 0.16957052, 0.09629893, 0.07310294]),
          np.array([0.14633129, 0.45458744, 0.20096238, 0.02142105, 0.17669784]), 
          np.array([0.41198731, 0.06197812, 0.05934063, 0.23325626, 0.23343768]), 
          np.array([0.15686545, 0.29516415, 0.20095091, 0.14720275, 0.19981674]), 
          np.array([0.15965914, 0.18383683, 0.10606946, 0.14234812, 0.40808645])]
tmp = np.asarray([0.01391123, 0.01388155, 0.17221067, 0.02675524, 0.01033257])

print(matrix @ tmp)  # [0.04171218 0.04535276 0.02546353 0.04688848 0.03106443]
print(tmp @ matrix)  # [0.07995043 0.03485222 0.02184015 0.04721548 0.05323298]
```

To make it a little more obvious what your code is doing, you might also consider using [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) instead of `@`. If you pass `matrix` as the first argument and `tmp` as the second, it will have the result you want, and make it more clear that you're conceptually calculating dot products rather than multiplying matrices.

---

As an additional note, if you're performing matrix operations on `matrix`, it might be better if it was a single two-dimensional array instead of a list of 1-dimensional arrays. this will prevent errors of the sort you'll see right now if you try to run `matrix @ matrix`. This would also let you say `matrix.dot(tmp)` instead of `np.dot(matrix, tmp)` if you wanted to.

(I'd guess that you can use [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) or a similar function to create `matrix`, or you can call `np.stack` on `matrix` after creating it.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Because `tmp` has only one dimension and `matrix` has two, NumPy can and will treat `tmp` as whichever type of vector makes the multiplication work (using [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)). So `tmp` is treated as a column vector in `matrix @ tmp` and a row vector in `tmp @ matrix`.

Comment: Nice result, but this is only makes sense if there is some object dynamically can affect the data or OP's mistaken.

Comment: I don't get any changes when I switch tmp and matrix in my function so i guess i get a problem with a format. I will just reformat matrix as a (5,5) array tomorrow I will keep u updated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YannPOURCENOUX Why you accept this answer - though it is fine and can be correct -, if you didn't proved, if it is correct. If it is correct, that you missed something, in this case we have to step away, but if not we should work on solution.

Comment: Thanks I did not see i did it. Should have been a missclicked with the touchpad while I was looking elsewhere haha

Comment: I reshaped matrix as a (5,5) ndarray of float type and it is now working as expected. Thanks, I'll be more carefull with types next time :D